# Spinner issue in the MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following UI, and it displays gender list when user clicks.

**View.axml**

```
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatSpinner
 android:layout_width="80dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 local:MvxBind="ItemsSource GenderList; SelectedItem GenderCategory" />
```

However in the following corresponding `ViewController`, no matter what user chooses, it always keep the initial value. For example if spinner shows `Female`, even though user chooses `Male`, it keeps showing `Female`.

**ViewController.cs**

```
private List<string> _genderList = new List<string>() { "Female", "Male" };

public List<string> GenderList
{
  get { return _genderList ; }
  set { _genderList = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => GenderList); }
}

public string GenderCategory
{
    get
    {
      var a = Model.Persons.Where(x => x.PId("12").FirstOrDefault().Gender;
      if (a.Equals(Constants.Category.Female))
      {
         return "Female";
      }
      else
      {
          return "Male";
      }
    }
    set
    {
       if (value.Equals("Female"))
          Model.SetGender(Constants.Category.Female, Person.Age);
       else {
          Model.SetGender(Constants.Category.Male, Person.Age);
       }
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Gender);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `Model.Persons.Where(x => x.PId("12").FirstOrDefault().Gender` return? Is it possible that this value is "Female"? Which would mean that the spinner will always show "Female" as the selected gender regardless of what the user selects.

Comment: yes It returns "Female", but it is just getting, is not it ? I am trying to set the spinner to "Male". Local database stores person information and I am calling that method to find the initial value of gender, in other words, I am trying to get the corresponding gender value before I changed or set it to something else.

Comment: Instead of using a Spinner for Genders, why don't you use a Radio Group instead? I find that more intuitive, also remember to add an "Other" option, because some people don't identify as either. As @PlaceHold3r suggests, you are _always_ returning whatever `a` is from your Model in your getter, which probably is your problem.

Comment: I simplified the issue that I have here, therefore I used `Gender` rather than having huge list of selection. I understand that it always return Female in the get method. But how do you get the initial value when UI is loading?

Comment: the value returned from `GenderCategory` is used by the `SelectedItem` binding to match to the  `ItemsSource` binding. Therefore, by return "Female" the `SelectedItem` is set as "Female" and so your spinner will not change to "Male"  when selected by the user

Comment: @PlaceHold3r,  ok but how could I able to solve the issue? I should somehow initialize selectedItem before user changes to other values? could you please illustrate your explanation into code?

Comment: Lets assume that you have 15 persons in the local database. and I want to see personID 12 . Initially how do you get the gender of person 12? Therefore I am calling that method in the `get` property.

Comment: make sure to return (via the get) the value that the user selected (via the set), probably the easiest would be through using a backing field

Comment: @PlaceHold3r, could you please illustrate your explanation into code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the backing field to return the user's selected option:

```
string _genderCategory;
public string GenderCategory
{
    get
    {
        return _genderCategory ?? GenderList.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals("Female"))
            Model.SetGender(Constants.Category.Female, Person.Age);
        else
        {
            Model.SetGender(Constants.Category.Male, Person.Age);
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Gender);

        _genderCategory = value;
    }
}
```

*Edited: to include a default select first gender option*